# Where to start with Android development in 2021?

Tags: android, mobile-development

I searched for this question here and there are lots of answers, but they are all outdated. I googled it and saw answers but I'm curious about your personal experience in learnin android development. So where do I need to start and what should I learn to become Junior Android Developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step should be learning Kotlin. For that, I'd recommend enroll the Kotlin Developer course on Jetbrains Academy
https://hyperskill.org

Then you can get a taste of android with this free course on Udacity.
https://www.udacity.com/course/developing-android-apps-with-kotlin--ud9012

The complete roadmap which you can follow
https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-developer-roadmap

You'll find various tutorials on YouTube for every stage in this roadmap. You can even follow Google's Codelabs for various topics.
Think of building something like Instagram/Whatsapp clone. You'll learn a lot while building something on your own.